# Background image covers whole space ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Doing my mini-game I met a bug.
There's a Storyboard of View Controller that doing all stuf 
I created an image-view called "backgrounder" and the first times it was ok , but then backgrounder covered the whole space , I tryed to delete background-image and create again but there's same bug . Tryed to Editor->arrange->send to back but it's non-optional 
How to fix that? There's a screentshot of that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh33Q.jpg)

Comment: What your exact issue? not getting properly. are you saying that when you run your project you can only see background image and unable to display another content?

Comment: @Lion yep that's it , but buttons are enabled if I click to that position then buttons do their actions

Comment: This is the problem of autolayout i think

Comment: try to use Debug View Hierarchy feature in Xcode

Comment: @Lion I've deleted all of autolayout but got the same http://puu.sh/oTUQJ/d29ddad7df.jpg

Comment: In Xcode, try dragging `Backgrounder` below other controls in the view hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background in view here:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image-name.jpg")!)
```

You can also set background color here:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not just setting the background color. You want to set an image with an UIImageView. You should be able to set it in Interface Builder. Anyway try to set it in code. In viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() just add:

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(yourBackgroundView)
```

It should send your view to the back. "yourBackgroundView" is the UIImageView you set up in interface builder. Create an IBOutlet to be able to access it in code. The method before should do the job.

Comment: If he already uses IB and storyboards, I think it's better if he just sets the right view hierarchy via IB itself